# No se ejecuta mi programa .exe en otros pcs

Tags: java, launch4j

Tengo un código en java que convertí en archivo .jar y cuando abro ese archivo .jar en mi pc funciona bien, luego pase este archivo .jar a archivo .exe a través de Launch4j el problema es que cuando le pongo otra versión más baja que no sea la que tiene mi pc en el apartado JRE no me corre el programa .exe ni aparece ningún error. Cuando le pongo la versión de java que tiene mi pc que es 20.0.1 si me corre el archivo .exe en este pc pero en otros no. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que pasa si ejecutas a mano el jar en otro equipo desde la línea de comandos? Algún mensaje de error?

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece ser que tienes la versión más reciente de `JRE` y estás construyendo tu archivo `.exe` bajo esa misma versión, de ese modo en todos los equipos donde planees correr ese `.exe` necesitarán la misma versión de `JRE`.

Yo te recomendaría bajar de versión para hacer un `.exe` más estándar para todos los equipos, puedes descargar versiones antiguas [aquí](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/archive/).

Si comentas que bajas la versión y no funciona, verifica que tengas bien la instalación, esto puedes hacerlo desde consola ejecutando el comando `java -version` y desde tus variables de ambiente ejecutando el comando `set` (para Windows) y `echo $PATH` (para Linux/Mac) y buscando la variable `JAVA_HOME`.